# Starting an nREPL with Clojure CLI Tools

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface, nrepl

How do I start an nREPL from the `clj` command?

I can't run my project using Lein or Boot because I have an unbalanced paren somewhere, and the reader complains `java.lang.RuntimeException: read-cond starting on line 13 requires an even number of forms.

Answer (score 9):

Things are easier now than they were when the question was posted:

```
$ clj -Sdeps '{:deps {nrepl/nrepl {:mvn/version "0.5.3"}}}' -m nrepl.cmdline
```

More details [here](https://nrepl.org/nrepl/usage/server.html#_using_clojure_cli_tools).

Answer (score 3):

Wrote [a gist](https://gist.github.com/theronic/84bf4c315246deef9876d6d0837b8436) on how to do this:

```
clj -Sdeps '{:deps {org.clojure/tools.nrepl {:mvn/version "0.2.12"}}}'
Clojure 1.9.0
user=> (use '[clojure.tools.nrepl.server :only (start-server stop-server)])
nil
user=> (defonce server (start-server :port 7888))
#'user/server
```

Now you can connect to port 7888 using your remote REPL client. There is probably a way to do this in one line.

Comment: You can even use gists with tools.deps.alpha, see https://gist.github.com/bhb/2686b023d074ac052dbc21f12f324f18